# How can I set the width/height of td tag in which image is included?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to set the width and height of **td** tag , which have and  tag inside. So , what I want to do is , no matter whatever the image size is , but it should be taken according to the width/height of **td** tag.

Example:

If image size is **200 * 100** and **td** tag's width and height is **100*50**. then it should take **100 * 50** , according to the width and height of **td** tag.

```html
<tr>
  <td valign="top" align="center" id="animate" style="color: #FFFFFF;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height: 0px;letter-spacing:1px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;" width="100" height="100"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws/images/event/logo/thumb/2712_1455295221.png" width="70" height="70" ></td>
</tr>
```

I can't use  **`position`**  property for the same.

Comment: Wrap the `img` in a `div` or give `img` `display:block`, then give the `div` or `img` (according to whichever option you choose), explicit dimensions.

Comment: I don't think this will work, but you could try setting max-width: 100%; and max-height:100% on the image e.g. #animate img {max-width:100%; max-height:100%;}

Comment: I can't use **div** tag. have to strictly stick to table tag. as I am making HTML emailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
display:block;
width:100%;
height:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `<img>` `width: 100%` and `height:auto`

Enter a number in the box and it will set the `<td>` to that dimension, the `<img>` will conform.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('#in1').on('input', function() {
  var dim = $(this).val();
  $('#animate').height(dim).width(dim);
});
```

```css
img { width: 100%; height:auto}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center" id="animate" style="color: #FFFFFF;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height: 0px;letter-spacing:1px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;" width="50" height="50">
      <img src='http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws/images/event/logo/thumb/2712_1455295221.png'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id='in1'>
```